# What do the numbers in a man page mean?

Tags: man

So, for example, when I type `man ls` I see `LS(1)`. But if I type `man apachectl` I see `APACHECTL(8)` and if I type `man cd` I end up with `cd(n)`.

I'm wondering what the significance of the numbers in the parentheses are, if they have any.

Comment: Version on [Super User](http://superuser.com/faq): *[What do the parentheses and number after a Linux command or C function mean?](http://superuser.com/questions/297702)*

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/62936/what-does-the-number-in-brackets-shown-after-unix-command-names-mean

Comment: On a side note, you can set your own search order with `export MANSECT=0p:1:2:3:3p:4:5:6:7:8:9:l:s:n`

Comment: Many answers state that p stands for POSIX, but just witnessing what is installed on my Debian distribution, in some cases p can (also, instead) stand for Perl. There are also .3pm for perl module libraries, 3posix etc... depending where it's found. Here 1p consistently stands for Perl, while 1posix exists for POSIX. Unless p is defined by POSIX, there's no reason to assume p means POSIX.

Comment: [Linux manpage](https://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/)

Answer (score 781, accepted):

The number corresponds to what section of the manual that page is from; 1 is user commands, while 8 is sysadmin stuff. The man page for man itself (`man man`) explains it and lists the standard ones:

```
MANUAL SECTIONS
    The standard sections of the manual include:

    1      User Commands
    2      System Calls
    3      C Library Functions
    4      Devices and Special Files
    5      File Formats and Conventions
    6      Games et. al.
    7      Miscellanea
    8      System Administration tools and Daemons

    Distributions customize the manual section to their specifics,
    which often include additional sections.
```

There are certain terms that have different pages in different sections (e.g. `printf` as a command appears in section 1, as a `stdlib` function appears in section 3); in cases like that you can pass the section number to `man` before the page name to choose which one you want, or use `man -a` to show every matching page in a row:

```
$ man 1 printf
$ man 3 printf
$ man -a printf
```

---

You can tell what sections a term falls in with `man -k` (equivalent to the `apropos` command). It will do substring matches too (e.g. it will show `sprintf` if you run `man -k printf`), so you need to use `^term` to limit it:

```
$ man -k '^printf'
printf               (1)  - format and print data
printf               (1p)  - write formatted output
printf               (3)  - formatted output conversion
printf               (3p)  - print formatted output
printf [builtins]    (1)  - bash built-in commands, see bash(1)
```

Note that the section can sometimes include a subsection (e.g., the `p` in `1p` and `3p` above).  The `p` subsection is for POSIX specifications; the `x` subsection is for X Window System documentation.

Comment: Note that these section numbers are for Linux. 1, 3 and 6 are the same across all unix variants AFAIK, but the others and the non-lone-digit sections can differ. Usually `man X intro` describes what is in section `X`.

Comment: @Giles The single digit sections 1-5 are pretty well standardized across all Unix variants, going back to the original Unix from Bell Labs.

Comment: @KeithB: I've used some unices with different 4,5,7,8. Digital Unix (OSF1) had, and Solaris still has: file formats in 4, misc in 5, devices in 7. Solaris also puts administrator commands in 1m. I think system calls in 2 is universal, but some systems also have some C library interfaces in 2 (when they're supposed to be thin wrappers around the eponymous syscall).

Comment: `man -w -a` will show paths to all versions of manpage without displaying them.

Comment: or:
    `$ whatis printf` from man 1.6 (instead of 'man -k "^printf"')

Comment: Huh, who'da thought you'd need a manual to use a manual... Never have I ever executed `man man`... until now.

Comment: Sadly, 'man man' does not list the sections on every platform.  (Looking at you, OS X.)  Shall we incorporate this into the otherwise great answer?

Comment: FreeBSD has kernel interface documentation in section 9.

Answer (score 79):

The history of these section numbers goes back to the original [Unix Programmer's Manual](https://www.bell-labs.com/usr/dmr/www/manintro.html) by Thompson and Ritchie in 1971.

The original sections were

1. Commands
2. System calls
3. Subroutines
4. Special files
5. File formats
6. User-maintained programs
7. Miscellaneous

Comment: More stuff from the 70ies, indeed. I thought it was from the 80ies.

Comment: "Miscellaneous" primarily means "broad information about an entire subsystem or generic Unix feature rather than a particular API endpoint."  See for example `pipe(7)`, `tcp(7)` (and several other networking man pages), `pthreads(7)`, `boot(7)`, `regex(7)`, etc.  There's other stuff in section 7 as well, such as `ascii(7)` (ASCII table) and `man(7)` (how to write a man page) but the broad docs pages are by far the most useful things in section 7 in my experience.

Answer (score 47):

konqueror also describes non-standard sections: (thanks to @greg0ire for the idea)

```
0     Header files
0p    Header files (POSIX)
1     Executable programs or shell commands
1p    Executable programs or shell commands (POSIX)
2     System calls (functions provided by the kernel)
3     Library calls (functions within program libraries)
3n    Network Functions
3p    Perl Modules
4     Special files (usually found in /dev)
5     File formats and conventions eg /etc/passwd
6     Games
7     Miscellaneous  (including  macro  packages and conventions), e.g. man(7), groff(7)
8     System administration commands (usually only for root)
9     Kernel routines
l     Local documentation
n     New manpages
```

Answer (score 29):

What it's means already described, but I also wants to add that each section has special manual page with introduction: `intro`. For example, see `man 1 intro` or `man 3 intro` and so on.

Comment: I don't see this on my Fedora install. Is man X intro not standard?

Comment: @tjameson Do you have `man-pages` package installed?

Comment: It's there in openSUSE Leap 15.3.

Answer (score 21):

From the `man` manpage:

```
The table below shows the section numbers of the manual followed by the 
types of pages they contain.

   1   Executable programs or shell commands
   2   System calls (functions provided by the kernel)
   3   Library calls (functions within program libraries)
   4   Special files (usually found in /dev)
   5   File formats and conventions eg /etc/passwd
   6   Games
   7   Miscellaneous  (including  macro  packages and conven‐
       tions), e.g. man(7), groff(7)
   8   System administration commands (usually only for root)
   9   Kernel routines [Non standard]
```

As to why they're separate like that -- there's some overlap. Certain manpages exist in more than one section depending on what you mean.

For instance, compare `man crontab` with `man 5 crontab` -- chances are the latter is the one you meant to look up.

Comment: And what are `man1p` and `man3p`?

Comment: And where should I place my own manpages located in `~/man`?

Comment: 1p is the posix standard version of the manual. If you want to write portable code, you should use only Xp man pages. If you implementation is non posix compliant X and Xp man pages could differ.

Comment: @Tyilo see my answer

Comment: Also read the middle-part of the first line; for example it says "POSIX Programmer's Manual" for "1p" as opposed to "User Commands" for "1" (here on Linux at least).

Answer (score 11):

These are section numbers.
Just type `man man` or open konqueror and type man://man and you'll see what are these sections.

Answer (score 11):

Often, a man page is referenced via suffixing it with the section enclosed in parentheses, e.g.:

```
read(2)
```

This style has two main advantages:

- it is immediately clear that you reference a man page - i.e. you can write something like 'cf. read(3)' instead of 'cf. the section 3 man page of read'
- if multiple sections contain man pages with the same name, specifying the section is more precise

Man pages are organized in sections, e.g. Section 1 includes all user command man pages, Section 2 all man pages for the system calls, Section 3 is for library functions etc.

On the command line, if you don't explicitly specify the section you get the first matching man page, in the default section traversal order, e.g.:

```
$ man read
```

displays `BASH_BUILTINS(1)` on Fedora. Where

```
$ man 2 read
```

displays the man page for the `read()` system call.

Note that the positional specification of the section is not portable - e.g. on Solaris you would specify it like this:

```
$ man -s 2 read
```

Usually, `man man` also lists some of the available sections. But not necessarily all. For listing all available sections one may list the subdirectories of all directories listed in the default man path or the environment variable `$MANPATH`. For example on a Fedora 23 system with some development packages installed `/usr/share/man` has following subdirectories:

```
cs  es  id  man0p  man2   man3x  man5x  man7x  man9x  pt_BR  sk  zh_CN
da  fr  it  man1   man2x  man4   man6   man8   mann   pt_PT  sv  zh_TW
de  hr  ja  man1p  man3   man4x  man6x  man8x  pl     ro     tr
en  hu  ko  man1x  man3p  man5   man7   man9   pt     ru     zh
```

The directories with the `man` prefix represent each section - while the other ones contain translated sections. Thus, to get a list of non-empty sections one could issue a command like this:

```
$ find /usr/share/man -type f  | sed 's@^.*/man\(..*\)/.*$@\1@' \
    | sort -u | column
0p  1p  3   4   6   8
1   2   3p  5   7
```

(the sections ending with `p` are POSIX man pages)

To view a man page in another language (if available) one can set a language related environment variable, e.g.:

```
$ LC_MESSAGES=de_DE man read
```

Also, each section should have an introduction man page named `intro`, e.g. viewable via:

```
$ man 2 intro
```

Answer (score 7):

The definitions for SVr4 are:

```
1 User Commands
2 System Calls
3 library Functions
4 File Formats
5 Standards, Environment and Macros (e.g. man(5))
6 Games and Demos
7 Device and Network Interfaces, Special Files
8 Maintenance Procedures
9 Kernel and Driver entry points and structures
```

These is the actual numbering for a "genetic" UNIX. 
POSIX does not define numbers.

Answer (score 2):

Trying to be a bit more exhaustive than the `man man` page, that is already a really good starting point:

- **man1**: User programs Manual pages that describe publicly accessible commands are contained in this chapter. Most program documentation that a user will need to use is located here. Also, self developed scripts that comes in handy in daily tasks will be stored here.
- **man2**: *System calls* This section describes all of the system calls (requests for the kernel to perform operations).
- **man3**: *Library functions and subroutines*; program library routines that are not direct calls to kernel services. This and chapter 2 are only really of interest to programmers.
- **man4**: *Special files*; special files, related driver functions, and networking support available in the system. Typically, this includes the device files found in `/dev` and the kernel interface to networking protocol support.
- **man5**: *File formats*; formats for many data files. This includes various include files, program output files, and system files.
- **man6**: *Games*; games, demos, and generally trivial programs. Different people have various notions about how essential this is.
- **man7**: *Miscellaneous Manual*; pages that are difficult to classify are designated as being section 7. The troff and other text processing macro packages are found here.
- **man8**: *System administration*; Programs used by system administrators for system operation and maintenance are documented here. Some of these programs are also occasionally useful for normal users. `ifconfig`, `mount`, `purge`, for example, are all stored here.