# No manual page for regex in section 3 - where is it?

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, debian, man

I found [What do the numbers in a man page mean?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3586/what-do-the-numbers-in-a-man-page-mean) which explains the sections for command/library documentation quite nicely, and I was looking at the output for `man regex` and noticed the See Also referred to `regex(3)`.

I tried to run `man 3 regex`, but got the following message:

```
No manual page for regex in section 3
```

My question is - where is it?

This is on Ubuntu 10.04 if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> REGEX(3)
>
> NAME 
>   regcomp, regexec, regerror, regfree - POSIX regex functions

Works fine here on Arch Linux and also on the [Internet](http://linux.die.net/man/3/regex)...

You might need to (re)install them:

```
sudo apt-get install manpages manpages-dev manpages-posix manpages-posix-dev
```

Comment: yeah, the section 3 page for regex was not already installed - fixed, thanks

Answer (score 4):

In Ubuntu this man page belongs to `manpages-dev` package.

Answer (score 4):

You need to install the `manpages-dev` package:

```
$ dpkg -S /usr/share/man/man7/regex.7.gz
manpages: /usr/share/man/man7/regex.7.gz

$ dpkg -S /usr/share/man/man3/regex.3.gz
manpages-dev: /usr/share/man/man3/regex.3.gz
```

Practically all the man pages in sections 2 and 3 come from the `manpages-dev` package.

I guess this is because they take up about 20 MB, and some users don't need them.

(There are also some man pages provided by the various `*-dev` packages and programming language specific packages, e.g. `*-perl`.)

If ever you can't find a file, but you know part of its name, `apt-file` can help:

```
$ apt-file search regex.3.gz
...
manpages-dev: /usr/share/man/man3/regex.3.gz
...
```

Answer (score 0):

On my gentoo system `man regex` only gives me the section 3 (POSIX syscall) man page.  (What manual section did *your* `man regex` retrieve it's man page? Just curious.)

Running a `equery belongs /usr/include/regex.h` on my system reveals that that header file is part of the `sys-libs/glibc` package.  Similarly, by running the command `equery belongs /usr/share/man/man3/regex.3.bz3` I found out that the man page for the `regex.h` file is provided by the package `sys-apps/man-pages`.

Now, I imagine Gentoo and Ubuntu might have different ways of organizing their manfiles, but I think it is worth a shot for you to check if you got some man-page related package not installed on your host.  I take for granted that your machine has Ubuntu's `glibc` package installed (otherwise I would find it hard to believe that your system even boots up), you should have the file `/usr/include/regex.h` available on your system (unless Ubuntu has decided to have it elsewhere, like `/usr/local/include/regex.h`).

Comment: `man regex` returns the page from section 7 on my Ubuntu install