# What are the difference between man1, man2, man3... folders?

Tags: man

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What do the numbers in a man page mean?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3586/what-do-the-numbers-in-a-man-page-mean)

What are the differences between man*X* pages?
Why are they separated?