# How to follow links in linux man pages?

Tags: man, hypertext

Is there a way to follow the links mentioned in a man page? For example, here's the man page for `ps`; how do I access the underlined link circled in red in the screenshot: `top(1)`?

[image: Screenshot of the ps man page]

Comment: Also, I see that `man is an interface to the on-line reference manuals` which (if I am not wrong) means it should be pulling all the info from some webpage on the internet, right? So, anyone has a clue as to what the http:// link is?

Comment: Here “on-line” means “on the computer” (as opposed to “on paper”), not “on the Internet”.

Comment: **"On-Line":** You might remember those "Adventure" Quest games for PC that were put out by a company (then) named Sierra On-Line. **man pages:** The best way to browse man pages is to use your editor. That way, navigating, searching (etc.) the text will be so smooth as every shortcut is in your muscle-memory since long. Also, say you work on a programming project - you could copy from man pages into your code. Nothing less than seamless interaction. Check out [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/45323/13136) and my comment to @Gilles ' [answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/18161/13136).

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Man pages date back to [Unix First Edition](http://man.cat-v.org/unix-1st/). While [hypertext](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext) had been invented, it was still in infancy; the web was two decades away, and the manual was an actual printed book, often with one command per page if they fit (that's why they were called pages).

The format used for manual pages has evolved somewhat since then, but most pages aren't really designed for hypertext, and the default `man` program doesn't support it (it's just a plain text viewer, with hacks to support some basic formatting). There are however man page viewing programs that reconstruct some hyperlinks, mainly links to other man pages, which are traditionally written in the form `man(1)` where `man` is the name of the man page and `1` is the [section number](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3586/what-do-the-numbers-in-a-man-page-mean):

- [tkman](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tkman/), a GUI man page viewer with hyperlinks
- [WoMan](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/woman.html) ([wiki](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/WoMan), [man comparsion](http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/modernization_man_page.html), [formerly](http://centaur.maths.qmw.ac.uk/emacs/woman/)), a man page browser for Emacs, supporting hyperlinks
- [man2html](http://www.nongnu.org/man2html/), a man to HTML converter (plus a web browser to read the result)

You can browse the manual pages of several operating systems, converted to HTML by `man2html` or similar tools, on a number of sites online, for example:

- [Arch Linux](https://man.archlinux.org/)
- [CentOS](https://man.linuxtool.net/)
- [Debian](https://manpages.debian.net/cgi-bin/man.cgi)
- [FreeBSD](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi) (and a bunch of other collections)
- macOS: [archive from 10.9 Mavericks](https://web.archive.org/web/20180513005254/https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/indexguts.html#group_Section_1), [recent version at unix.com](https://www.unix.com/man-page-mojave-repository.php), [partial copy at ss64.com](https://ss64.com/osx/)
- [MINIX 3](https://www.minix3.org/manpages/)
- [NetBSD](https://man.netbsd.org/)
- [OpenBSD](https://man.openbsd.org/)
- [Solaris 10](https://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19253-01/index.html), [Solaris 11](https://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19963-01/index.html), [other Solaris versions](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/documentation/legacy-solaris-192993.html)
- [Ubuntu](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/)
- [Unix 1st edition](https://man.cat-v.org/unix-1st/), [Unix 6th edition](https://man.cat-v.org/unix-6th/), [Unix 8th edition](https://man.cat-v.org/unix_8th/)

Some time after man pages had become the established documentation format on unix and some time before the web was invented, the [GNU](http://www.gnu.org/) project introduced the [info](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Info_%28Unix%29) documentation format, more advanced than man while sticking to simple markup designed for text terminals. The major innovation of info compared to man was to have multi-page documentation with hyperlinks to other pages. Info is still the prefered documentation format for GNU projects, though most Info pages are generated from a [Texinfo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Texinfo) source (or sometimes other formats) that can also generate HTML. When info documentation for a program exists, it's often the main manual, while the man pages only contain basic information about command line arguments.

Comment: Great answer! Also worth mentioning is that there is another mode for man pages in Emacs, the one (at least I) get by just `M-x man` (and `C-h v mode-name` is `Man`): at least in one aspect, it is superior to `WoMan` because it displays tables ([screenshot](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/45093/13136)). Of course, it is hyperlinked as well.

Comment: The info program user interface feels just wrong and counter-intuitive. I haven't seen anyone using that.

Comment: @PavelŠimerda> *The info program user interface feels just wrong and counter-intuitive.* <  Emm, compared to what?  To less(1) (which is default pager for man(1) in GNU) — that thing, where you have to recall how to *scroll back*, since <backspace> is not bound (and <pgup> might not work at all)?  The primary key is `b`, by that way.  To a user of which interface paradigm this might be intuitive?

Comment: @PavelŠimerda> *I haven't seen anyone using that.*  <  Always use info(1) for reading manpages when got locked in a text terminal for the exact reason, that unlike less(1) it *does* convert dumb `page(N)` links into hyperlinks.  Was quite suprised that is was not mentioned in Gilles’ answer in that quality.

Comment: It could be useful to remind that in `info`, one can follow links (weirdly formatted as `*link text::`) by moving the cursor on it (or Tab) and hitting Enter. Also it seems to me that info accepts all sorts of emacs commands, but it's too tricky for me (I use vim).

Comment: `info` is great once you get the hang of it.  Just remember to hit `m` to access menus, `g` to jump to any section (you can tab-complete them), `i` to access the index (very handy!), and read `info info` to dive deeper.  At least one system takes extra care to offer info manuals, GNU Guix.  There you can access for example the `QEMU` and `CMake` manuals, which are horribly long to refer to in their man page format.

Answer (score 48):

First of all, it's not a link. It's just an underline. Man pages are just text documents with a little bit of simple formatting that a terminal can handle. The underline is just a highlight, there is no "link" involved.

The normal `man` command is just a text formatter. In fact the `man` command doesn't even display the text, `man` just formats the information stored in the man page file<sup>[1]</sup> and sends the formatted output to another program (usually `less`) that displays the formatted output to the screen. These display programs have no concept of links.

There are some special documentation readers that might be able to look at formatting like that and make an educated guess that such a highlight might indicate that there is a related man page that could be pulled up and create a link, but I don't know which ones do. Perhaps `pinfo`?

If you want web like formatting with hyperlinks you can find almost any UNIX man page online with links added in. Try typing `man [anything]` into google and you will almost certainly get one in the first couple hits.

In the case of your example, the visual highlighting is a clue that that is another program name that has it's own man page that you can easily pull up. Try `man 1 top`. The 1 indicates the section of the man pages to look in. See this question for an explanation of the sections: [What do the numbers in a man page mean?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/3586/1925)

---

<sup>[1]</sup> If you open the `man` page file in a text editor, you will see the raw `man` page that is not formatted for easy reading. The raw `man` page is written in a markup language called `troff`. For more information on `troff` and how to write a `man` page see: https://liw.fi/manpages/ .

Comment: Any idea why it is `man 1 top` ?? I mean it should be something like `ps 1 top` because I found the link on the man page for `ps`. "man 1 top" doesn't make sense to me. Please clarify.

Comment: There are also some resources that make man pages available on the internet, with references replaced by href's, which are clickable.

Comment: If you want to follow `top(1)` "link", you need to open `top` manual page from 1st section. For more information about sections see man(1). `ps 1 top` does not makes any sense, since you'll just run `ps` command with some strange to it params.

Comment: @Aahan it's man 1 top because you want to see the manual page for the top command in the 1st section of the online manual pages.  The reference top(1) means just that, top in the 1st section of the manual pages.  To see that, you type "man 1 top" at the prompt.  See "man man"

Comment: ohkay! I finally get it. I thought that reference was related to "ps." Thanks for the clarification @Caleb, gabe and rvs.

Comment: @Aaran: The "sections of the manual cover different topics. Section 1 is user commands (stuff you type at the prompt) section 2 is system calls and so on. Some strings appear n more than one section. On the machine I am on right now `readlink` appears in section 1 and section 2 and `printf` in sections 1 and 3. If you just type `man command`, man trys sections in numeric order and displays the first it finds, or you can be specific with `man # command`, which you have to do to get the documentation for the `readlink` system call.

Answer (score 20):

I recommend [`w3mman`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/w3mman), the system’s manual pager through the w3m command-line browser. It colors links and enables tabbing through them

You can try it by installing the `w3m` package, which is available in most software repositories and Cygwin.

Comment: A late reply that adds some answer to the question that is not mentioned yet, it never a problem! Welcome at Unix&Linux StackExchange!

Comment: `w3mman` is also provided with the default Macports `w3m` installation. It's great :) Thanks!

Answer (score 13):

Let me try to interpret your question a bit more in a sense in which I try to follow your workflow. What you probably would like to have is a key combination within a `man` page that leads you directly to the underlined commands you are reading about. So, not having to install something else, nor opening up another console and forgetting the exact syntax for example.

This simplest solution is the exclamation mark (if you are using `less` to display the man pages) and you want to go to the underlined `top`:

```
!man top
```

Or

```
!man 1 top
```

You will have to close them all by pressing `q` multiple times. Note also that this won't work if `LESSSECURE=1` is set as environmental variable which would make run `less` in secure mode and not allow you to use `!`. It will tell you something like "Command not available".

Comment: This is not an answer to the question. Saying this is "a key combination" is gross dishonesty to say the least. First it's not dynamic, you have to type the name of the word under the cursor manually, so it's strictly not a key combination since it changes every for every different target. Secondly, since you're resorting to technicalities, you're spawning another process so this is not "within a man page". We could make the exact same argument saying "You can use the key combination `qman 1 top` from within the man page!" With this in mind, I hope you can realize the bad faith of your post.

Comment: @adamency I think the term "gross dishonesty" is excessive and in general this is a very aggressive comment which I think is unwarranted.

Comment: I think you are sidestepping my point because you are not willing to admit the dishonesty, or at the very least irrelevance or uselessness, of your original answer.

Comment: You're a disturbed individual

Comment: Great ad hominem, still shamelessly dodging the actual subject. What a model you are. Let's stop this conversation now. You are hopeless.

Answer (score 6):

I have a (couple of) hack(s).

### hack 1

Put this in your ~/.bashrc or your ~/.zshrc

```
function man(){
    for arg in "$@"; do
        vim -c 'execute "normal! :let no_man_maps = 1\<cr>:runtime ftplugin/man.vim\<cr>:Man '"${arg}"'\<cr>:wincmd o\<cr>"'
    done
}
```

Screenshot..

[image: manual in vim screenshot]

Asciinema..

https://asciinema.org/a/130131

Now..

1. when you type `man vim`, for example, it will open up this man page in *vim*

   - if you type `man man vim`, for example, it will first open `man`'s manual and after you exit vim, it will open `vim`'s manual
2. when you press <kbd>K</kbd> (that's capital `k`) when you are on another man page at the bottom (the *SEE ALSO* section), you will jump to this manual (unfortunately inside of **a less pager** -- this is because we have `let no_man_maps = 1`; if you don't do that, then vim will force `q` to be `:q` and you will be unable to record a macro easily, and vim may behave wonkily in other ways).

   - exiting this second manual you have entered will bring you back to the previous manual you were viewing
3. you get very pretty syntax highlighting since you have loaded *ftplugin/man.vim* and the ft is (automatically) set to `man`.
4. you can copy and paste, navigate freely in vim, and even modify the buffer and `:w ~/usefulfile`. You can do everything you would normally do in vim, including record macros, yank to clipboard with `"+y` (if you have `+clipboard`), etc, etc.

I find it much nicer than *less*.

The only minor setback I have found (which still exists if you use less as your pager) is if you want to have multiple manuals open in one vim session. I don't really see a way to do this.

A few notes:

1. if you try to save the buffer, you will get `E382: Cannot write, 'buftype' option is set`

   - I like that you cannot save as it prevents accidentally saving it
2. you can still save like `:w /tmp/man.man`

   - if you save it with a `.man` extension, then opening it up will set the filetype to `man` for you
   - if you do not save it with a `.man` extension, you can just set the ft to `man` by running `:set ft=man`
3. if you need to do things when opening up man pages you can use `autocmd VimEnter *.~ echom 'hooray, we are using vim for man pages!'`, for example.
4. I have put the following in my vimrc so that I can press <kbd>K</kbd> to try to open manual, and then press <kbd>G</kbd> to go back to previous manual:

---

```
augroup man
    autocmd!
    autocmd VimEnter *.~ nnoremap B :execute "normal! `Z"<cr>
    autocmd VimEnter *.~ nnoremap <buffer> K :execute "normal! mZyiw:Man \<lt>c-r>\"\<lt>cr>"<cr>
augroup END
```

---

### hack 2

put this in your ~/.bashrc or ~/.zshrc

```
function man(){
    declare -a args
    for arg in "$@"; do
        command man "$arg" > "/tmp/${arg}.man"
        args+=("/tmp/${arg}.man")
    done
    vim "${args[@]}"
}
```

Screenshot..

[image: multiple manuals in vim]

Asciinema..

https://asciinema.org/a/9Q6Si90Pi46cDVUknxFxfIwsv

This solves problem that **hack 1** and *less* face (now you can view multiple manuals in one buffer), but it is less elegant.

Notes:

1. **IMPORTANT** if you want **hack2** to work, then you must put `:let no_man_maps = 1` in your `~/.vimrc`. This is because vim will source `.../vim80/man.vim` and `q` will be forcibly remapped to `:q`.
2. there is more clean up involved (now you store every manual to */tmp/*.man*)
3. you can now, however, view multiple man pages in one session, as noted above
4. if you press <kbd>K</kbd>, you will still open a new vim session, however

   - if you want you can bind an autocmd (using an autocmd like the one above) to do something like `autocmd VimEnter man.~ nnoremap <buffer> K :execute "normal! Byt(:silent !man \<c-r>\" > /tmp/\<c-r>\".man\<cr>:edit /tmp/\<c-r>\".man\<cr>"` or something crazy like that (**untested**)

Comment: apologies for badly colored asciinema. The colors look a lot nicer in my terminal.

Answer (score 4):

You can set `vim` (or `nvim`) as the viewer for the man page:

```shell
export MANPAGER='nvim +Man!'
```

Then you can use `CTRL-]` to follow a tag, and `CTRL-t` or `CTRL-o` to go back a tag.

For more info, read the [plugin's documentation](https://neovim.io/doc/user/filetype.html#ft-man-plugin) and do `:h tag` in `nvim`.

Answer (score 3):

Specifically for Ubuntu, there is Yelp. It's installed by default and is by default able to display manual pages, although the invocation to do so, is not the same as that of the `man` command; an alias or a shell function can work around the latter point (depends on your shell).

```
yelp 'man:exit'
```

It will default to a section in a way I don't know. Reminder: to get the sections list for a manual topic, use `whatis`, as in `whatis exit`.

To request Yelp to display a manual page from a specific section, say 2, do:

```
yelp 'man:exit(2)'
```

Issues: yelp has bugs and be prepared to get multiple errors output when invoking it from the command line. There also, an alias or a custom shell function can help redirecting all errors to `/dev/null`

Answer (score 3):

Just thought I'd add my 2 pence.

I'm using the following to view man pages, I've aliased man to the below command (which if you use zsh will still provide autocomplete).

```
man --html='lynx --cfg=~/.lynx.cfg' <manpage>
```

With the following in `~/.lynx.cfg` which sets up keys for easy navigation and sets q to quit, like in man. I had to copy the `HELPFILE` entry from the main `/etc/lynx/lynx.cfg` otherwise the help was not displaying properly.

```
KEYMAP:k:UP_TWO                # Move display up two lines
KEYMAP:j:DOWN_TWO              # Move display down two lines
KEYMAP:K:UP_HALF                # Move display up half a page
KEYMAP:J:DOWN_HALF              # Move display down half a page
KEYMAP:h:PREV_LINK        # Move to the previous link or page
KEYMAP:l:NEXT_LINK        # Move to the next link or page
KEYMAP:q:ABORT
HELPFILE:file://localhost/usr/share/doc/lynx-common/lynx_help/lynx_help_main.html.gz
```

**Note**: you will need to install the groff package for this to work.

```
sudo apt install groff
```

The result is quite nice, since man is doing the conversion to html I expect its the best option for getting links working correctly.

[image: man with lynx]

Comment: Thanks! I like the color scheme, it seems more convenient to read with lynx than with yelp. Also the useful captions menu on top.

Answer (score 2):

Although **w3mman** is a solution to follow links, does not use all the screen (at least on ubuntu 12.10)

I prefer to use:

```
$ sudo -i
# apt-get install w3m man2html
# exit
$ alias man=' hman -P w3m'
```

add the last command to **~/.bash_aliases** or similar startup script to get it on every session.

The **-P w3m** is because first browser to hman is [lynx](http://lynx.browser.org/) or [sensible-browser](https://askubuntu.com/a/8255/89479) but I prefer [w3m](http://w3m.sourceforge.net/)

**hman** is a tool bundled on html2man. See [this](http://www.boutell.com/lsm/lsmbyid.cgi/002299)

If exit with confirmation is annoying to you, as to me is use [this](http://dryice.name/blog/freebsd/quit-w3m-without-confirmation/)

Comment: My mistake, the package must be html2man

Answer (score 2):

Like they said, it wasn't designed for it.

You can use `info man` and then hit enter once you're under *SEE ALSO* section on your item.

> info - read Info documents

Answer (score 1):

I was able to use the `--html` argument to `man` in order to open it in the browser defined by $BROWSER environment variable, so:

```
BROWSER=google-chrome man ps --help
```

I'm using Fedora. Not sure if this works for your distro, please test and report in comments.

Comment: The option seems recognized on Ubuntu 12.04, but it fails.

Comment: OK, the package `groff` needs to be installed. The `groff` command may be there while the package of the same name is not (the command comes with `groff-base`, not the full `groff` package). I do `man --html="surf file%c//%s" <command>`, and it's fine. There is very‑very limited hypertext though :-/ .