# Reading the man pages in my system with hyperlinks on a browser

Tags: man, documentation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to follow links in linux man pages?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18151/how-to-follow-links-in-linux-man-pages)

I can read man pages online, but they are not necessarily the same that I have installed on my system (i.e. for the same tool/version, etc.).

With this, is there a way to read the man pages **in my system** with hyperlinks on a browser? Alternatively, are there any other man-reading tools with support for hyperlinks across commands, parameters, favorites, etc.?

Comment: @Shawn Hmm, might be true... Haven't noticed it.

Comment: @Shawn and $rozcietrzewiacz, I think you are right, sorry for not having seen that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a program called `man2html` that... Does what its name suggests :) It can be either found installed from a separate package or already part of your system utilities.