# Emacs mode for man pages

Tags: emacs, man, roff

I'm translating man pages, and have run in to a few problems with Emacs.

1. How do you specify language? (With man, it looks like this `man -Lsv shutdown` for the Swedish "sv" subdirectory, if available.)
2. In the Emacs man mode, you can use **N** or **P** to jump forward or backward according to headers (in roff, they look like this: `.SH`). But, this doesn't work if the header includes one (or more) of the three special Swedish characters: Å, Ä, and Ö. It doesn't matter if I escape them (like this `\(:A`). (But they are correctly displayed.)
3. To view a work in project, I use for example `M-x man RET ./ls.1` (that is, the absolute path). This is great, because it is the same man mode as for viewing "real" manpages (those in /usr/share/man). Only, when I do some changes in the document, how do I refresh the manpage? `revert-buffer` says the buffer is not associated with a file (not true, but OK, I get it); `M-x load-file RET` seems to have lost track of the file; ... Ideas?

By the way, translating is a lot of fun!

**EDIT:** (see the first comment)
[image: Table]

Comment: [Woman Mode](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/WoMan) could be worth a try (`M-x woman` for `ls`, `M-x woman-find-file` for `ls.1`s absolute path); it has a `woman-locale` variable that *might* help with **1.**. (As far as I could find out it fails to solve 2. and 3.; has some more features, though.)

Comment: @sr_: Oh, didn't even know there was a second way! Certainly worth exploring. But, take a look at the dump above, Woman doesn't seem to draw tables. I think the easiest way to solve **3**. is to write a small Elisp function that is specific for the man page you currently work on. That's not pretty but it is OK since it takes some time translating even a short man page.

Comment: Tables in man pages?  I wasn't even aware of that possibility.  Quite nice, thought.

Comment: As for **1.**, `(setq Man-switches "-Lsv")`

Answer (score 3):

How to update the man page in man page mode while editing the roff source:

```
;;;; MAN / man
(defvar *curr-man* "~/mansv/ls.1")

(defun edman ()
  "edit the current work-in-progress man page"
  (interactive)
  (find-file *curr-man*) )

(defun upman () ; edit: better version of this function below
  "update the current work-in-progress man page"
  (interactive)
  (buffer-menu)
  (revert-buffer)
  (with-temp-buffer
    (progn
      (insert-buffer-substring "*Buffer List*")
      (beginning-of-buffer)
        (let ((man-buffer (format "*Man %s*" *curr-man*)))
          (if (word-search-forward man-buffer (point-max) t) ; t = nil on fail
            (kill-buffer man-buffer) ))
      (man *curr-man*)
      (edman)
      (kill-buffer "*Buffer List*") )))
```

**EDIT**

This version of `upman` is hopefully more stable. Note the introducton of a new global.

```
(defun upman ()
  "update the current work-in-progress man page"
  (interactive)
  (if (get-buffer *curr-man-file*) (save-buffer))
  (let ((man-buffer (format "*Man %s*" *curr-man*)))
    (if (get-buffer man-buffer) (kill-buffer man-buffer))
    (man *curr-man*)
    (edman) ))
```