# How do I check man pages for what single parameter of the command does?

Tags: man

Example: I am using  `tar -zxvf` command but I don't know what 'x' stands for.

How can I check this single parameter without having to scroll all the way through `man tar`?

Comment: Please check this [thread][1] on superuser.com.

  [1]: http://superuser.com/questions/441654/how-to-jump-to-a-particular-flag-in-a-unix-manpage

Answer (score 26, accepted):

#### Search

`x` is for `extract`.

After you are inside man, type `/-x`<kbd>enter</kbd> to search info about the -x parameter,
Press `n` to jump to the next -x match, and `N` for the previous

#### Search with Regex

For large man pages, or a common terms, a little regex can be used to narrow the search.

If you just want the main entry, you can use `/^ *-x` to remove most extraneous matches.
This works as most man pages are formatted with the entry indented with spaces.

- `^ *` matches the start of line, with zero to many spaces.
- `-x` is the search string.

Answer (score 11):

#### This works in RHEL6 with Bash

In `.bashrc`

add

```
function mans {
       man $1 | less -p "^ +$2"
}
```

start a new instance of bash

`$ bash`

now

```
mans ls -l
```

has the desired effect.

Answer (score 6):

You could also `grep` it out of the man page with some context:

```
man tar | grep -C5 -- '-x\b'
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use Emacs, `M-x man RET tar`, then `C-s -x`.

Hit `C-s` repeatedly until you get to the right place, then hit return.

`C-r` is the same, but backwards. (But both will wrap on a double strike at document top/bottom.)

Also, in cases like this (man page search), case *sensitive* search is preferable. Examine the `case-fold-search` variable.

The huge advantage of using your *editor* to view man pages is that you know all commands so well - navigation, copying, everything you'd like to do, you already know how.

Answer (score 1):

I usually do this

```
man tar | less -p '   -x'
```

If the pattern is found, less will start the page with it, the pattern here is 3 spaces before the parameter you are searching for. Not 100% reliable but usually works.

If the pattern is not found, then pressing enter will show the whole result, and then u can use `less` search functionality itself to search for the argument.

Answer (score 0):

I know that it's a bit old question so sorry for reviving but I've written this simple shell script that you can use:

```
function manopt() {
    mn=`man -P cat $1`
    for i in ${@:2}
    do
        echo $mn |  grep --color=always -A5 "^ *$i" | sed -En '/^$/q;p'
    done
}
```

Use it for example as:

```
➜ manopt ls -l -a
       -l     use a long listing format
       -a, --all
              do not ignore entries starting with .
```

Note that you can have as many arguments as you like but they have to be valid ones (and at the start of the line).

Answer (score 0):

In general, I just use that `man(1)` shows the formatted page using your favorite pager, at least `more(1)`, and in the (rather rigid) manpage format flag `-x` is described under `-x`, so a quick search rapidly zeroes in on that.

If if is a GNU program (or at least one with an `info` document), an info viewer (like the builtin one in `emacs(1)` or the standalone `pinfo(1)`) are a comfortable way of browsing the mandatory `Invoking` section, with full detail of how the program is called. Again, search is available.