# About the command and the number in the man

Tags: man

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What do the numbers in a man page mean?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3586/what-do-the-numbers-in-a-man-page-mean)

such as:

```
http://www.postfix.org/qmgr.8.html
The qmgr(8) daemon awaits t
```

what's the meaning of 8?

just don't know it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/587676/why-do-programs-in-unix-like-environments-have-numbers-after-their-name/587682#587682

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do a 'man man' to get more information. The numbers are the various topic section of man pages, 8 being System administration commands and stuff. I think this question has been answered before though.