# attr man page missing?

Tags: command-line, man, xattr

How does one search for certain manpages (such as http://linux.die.net/man/5/attr)? Trying:

> man attr

and

> man -K attr

don't seem to work.

Any ideas why?

Comment: man -k keyword # works for me. although check for MANPATH variable.. man -L

Comment: do you think it's possible that I don't have this manpage? I'm on a fresh install of Debian 6.04.

Comment: "Doesn't work"?  Please be more specific.  What exactly happens?  Do you get an error?

Comment: It just can't find it, but turns out I needed the attr package and not just libattr, so it works now!

Answer (score 1):

You can view it like this:

`man 5 attr`

For a full explanation, take a look [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/3587/15142)

Comment: I tried that as well. Is it possible that I actually don't have that specific manpage? (Edit: This refers to a fresh text install of Debian 6.04)

Comment: On Debian the `attr` command and the related man pages are in the [_attr_](http://packages.debian.org/squeeze/attr) package. Is it installed?

Comment: You're right, for some reason I thought the manpages were the libattr package, but installing attr fixed that. Thanks!

Comment: `apt-file` or packages.debian.org can tell you which package provides a given file.  e.g. http://packages.debian.org/search?searchon=contents&keywords=attr.5.gz&mode=path&suite=stable&arch=any