# What does the number mean in a man page?

Tags: linux, command-line, man, application

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What do the numbers in a man page mean?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3586/what-do-the-numbers-in-a-man-page-mean)

If I type`man ls`, I see`LS(1)` in the top left and top right corners of the manpage.

I also see programs on the internet being refered to this way.

ex. `man(1), xman(1x), apropos(1), makewhatis(8) and catman(8).`

What are these numbers (and in some cases letters)?

Comment: The original Unix manuals came in several binders, numbered 1 for user commands, 2 for system calls, 3 for library functions, 4 for "special files" (devices), 5 for file formats, 6 for games (extremely important! we all know this is _the_ reason for the machine, all the rest is just disguise ;-), 7 for conventions and such. To this they added folder `n` for new (experimental stuff), and some installations had a `l` folder for local stuff. For more details on section `S` do `man S intro`.

Comment: An important thing to note about this is that there may be multiple man pages with the same name in different sections, but you cannot tell that by just asking for `man whatever`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's the section number, see

```
man man
```

> A section, if provided, will direct man to look only in that section
>   of the manual.  The default action is to search in all of the
>   available sections, following a pre-
>           defined order and to show only the first page found, even if page exists in several sections.
>
> ```
>     The table below shows the section numbers of the manual followed by the types of pages they contain.
>
>
>     1   Executable programs or shell commands
>     2   System calls (functions provided by the kernel)
>     3   Library calls (functions within program libraries)
>     4   Special files (usually found in /dev)
>     5   File formats and conventions eg /etc/passwd
>     6   Games
>     7   Miscellaneous (including macro packages and conventions), e.g. man(7), groff(7)
>     8   System administration commands (usually only for root)
>     9   Kernel routines [Non standard]
> ```

By example, `stat` have 3 sections :

```
$ man -k stat | grep "^stat "
stat (1)             - display file or file system status
stat (2)             - get file status
stat (3p)            - get file status
```

So if you type

```
man 1 stat
```

it's not the same as

```
man 2 stat
```

Comment: *SysV* derived unixen (Solaris for example) have slightly different numbering, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man_page#Manual_sections

Comment: Every Unix has different sections, regardless of heritage.

Comment: What is the meaning of the  `p` in `stat(3p)`?.  Also in `m4(1p)` ? I believe it stands for  `POSIX` but I'm not entirely sure.