# Man folders and MANPATH

Tags: directory-structure, man

This thread [What do the numbers in a man page mean?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3586/what-do-the-numbers-in-a-man-page-mean) answers the question of the significance of the **numbers between parentheses within a man page**. My question is related.

I have a local installation of a package called [`ffmpeg`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ffmpeg). The build folder has the typical `bin`, `lib`, etc. and then the folder:

**`man/man1/`** with the following files:

```
ffmpeg-bitstream-filters.1  ffmpeg-scaler.1  libavdevice.3
ffmpeg-codecs.1             ffmpeg-utils.1   libavfilter.3
ffmpeg-devices.1            ffmpeg.1         libavformat.3
ffmpeg-filters.1            ffplay.1         libavutil.3
ffmpeg-formats.1            ffprobe.1        libswresample.3
ffmpeg-protocols.1          ffserver.1       libswscale.3
ffmpeg-resampler.1          libavcodec.3
```

My questions are:

1. Why is there a subfolder under `man` called `man1`? Why not just in `man`? And why the suffix `1`?
2. Which path should I add to `MANPATH`? The one pointing to `man` ? or `man/man1`?
3. What do the suffices in the files above mean? Are they the same numbers within parentheses described in [the thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3586/what-do-the-numbers-in-a-man-page-mean) I mentioned above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The suffixes (such as 1) correspond to the numbers mentioned in "What do the numbers in a man page mean?".  The represent *sections* of the manual.
2. "Which path should I add to MANPATH? The one pointing to man?" Yes (ie, not one of the inner man1, man2, etc. directories).
3. These have the same significance as the directory suffixes from #1.  Notice `man1` contains all .1 files, `man2` all .2 files, etc.

Comment: Thanks @goldilocks. Oddly, your answer to `Q3` is not consistent with the file hierarchy I have for `ffmpeg` (I have `.2` and `.3` files under `man1`). Any thoughts why?

Comment: Probably, laziness.  Do the section headers in parentheses match the suffix? (You can view a man page file directly with, eg. `man ./ffmpeg.2`, presuming there is such a file in ./; the .gz man pages are fine this way too.)  Anyway, if the page names are unique (so there is no possible ffmpeg-foobar.1, ffmpeg-foobar.2) then there can be no conflict -- I would guess the only issue *might* be if someone did a `man 2 ffmpeg-foobar` when ffmpeg-foobar.2 is in `man1`, depending on how the man system decides and finds a page by section.  Try it.