# What does the parenthesis mean in a command description like "mklost+found(8)"

Tags: command

When googling for linux commands, I often see a number in parenthesis like this:

> mklost+found(8)

What does it mean?
Is it a version number of the program, reference to some standard, or what?

Comment: not duplicate, as asker don't know whether it is referring to  a `man` page.

Comment: @Tejas where else do you see the name of a command followed by a number in parentheses?

Comment: You are right but still I think this question is different.

Comment: Still a reason to close as duplicate, so this closed question will redirect to the one it's duplicating. That prevents duplication of answers and people having to search all over the place and compare answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number refers the section in the system's reference manual in which the corresponding page resides, e.g. for command `date`, (*date(1)*, in your case), 1 refers to the "*user commands*" section, which can be accessed by executing the command `man 1 date`.

See also `man man`. It lists all the standard sections:

> The standard sections of the manual include:
>
> ```
>   1      User Commands
>
>   2      System Calls
>
>   3      C Library Functions
>
>   4      Devices and Special Files
>
>   5      File Formats and Conventions
>
>   6      Games et. Al.
>
>   7      Miscellanea
>
>   8      System Administration tools and Deamons
> ```

Distributions customize the manual section to their specifics, which often include additional sections.

Comment: You might as well just replace your answer with a link to http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/3587/33055.