# How does exec bash builtin work internally?

Tags: bash, exec

From [this](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-exec-113) link I get the following about exec bash builtin command:

> If command is supplied, it **replaces the shell** without creating a
>   new process.

How does it exactly replace the shell (i.e. how does it work internally)? Does the `exec*()` system call work the same?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, the `exec` builtin ultimately makes use of one of the `exec*()` family of system calls. So does running commands normally. It's just that when you use `exec`, it doesn't use the `fork()` system call first to create a new process, and the result is that the new command replaces the shell.

Comment: It might also be interesting to know that all `exec*()` system calls are built upon the `evecve()` call. The others are mostly here for developer convenience.

Comment: @JohnWHSmith: Huh, learned something new today. You can determine this by the man page organization; [`execve` is in section 2](https://linux.die.net/man/2/execve), while [the rest of the `exec` family is in section 3](https://linux.die.net/man/3/exec). [Section 2 is for system calls, while 3 is for C library functions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/3587/152396); the separation indicates that all but `execve` are being provided at the user level, while `execve` calls directly into the kernel (possibly with `libc` wrapping, but it's logically a system call). Never noticed that 'til today.

Answer (score 7):

I did a `strace` on a running `bash` instance. Then I invoked the command `exec sleep 100`. Now see what happend:

```
access("/bin/sleep", X_OK)              = 0
...
execve("/bin/sleep", ["sleep", "100"], [/* 14 vars */]) = 0
...
nanosleep({100, 0},
...
exit_group(0)                           = ?
```

So you can see, it happend nearly the same as when you call `sleep` the normal way. `bash` checks if executable permission (`X_OK`) is granted for `/bin/sleep` with the `access()` system call. Then `execve()` executes the program pointed to by filename. After `execve()` syscall, `sleep` has the control over the process. Does it's things: `nanosleep()`. It also kepps the same pid. After `sleep` ended the process ends too. Whether `sleep` nor `bash` is not running anymore.

**Evidence:**

In another window I watched the process with `ps`. Before running the command it looked like this:

```
$ ps -o stat,pid,cmd -p <pid>
Ss+  10905 -bash
```

And while running:

```
$ ps -o stat,pid,cmd -p <pid>
Ss+  10905 sleep 100
```

Afer `sleep` ended the process disapeared.

**What happend when I run it normally?**

```
access("/bin/sleep", X_OK)              = 0
...
clone(child_stack=0, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, child_tidptr=0x7f6c9fd089d0) = 19261
...
wait4(-1, [{WIFEXITED(s) && WEXITSTATUS(s) == 0}], WSTOPPED|WCONTINUED, NULL) = 19261
...
--- SIGCHLD (Child exited) @ 0 (0) ---
```

The execution permission is checked. Then a child process is created `clone()`. The `bash` instance is now in the background process group, `sleep` is in the foreground process group. And at last, the `wait4()` call waits until the child process ended (that needs 100 seconds).