# exec command won't accept xargs, hangs on command input

Tags: exec

I'm not super familiar with `exec`. I was running through some tests and examples. I wanted to pass a command written in a file to it. I'm expecting that command to be run with `exec` just as if it were run directly on the commandline. Here's what I set up and tried:

```
[kellyry@ch12ldvela00 ~]$ cat exec_test
ls
[kellyry@ch12ldvela00 ~]$ cat exec_test | exec
[kellyry@ch12ldvela00 ~]$ cat exec_test | xargs exec
xargs: exec: No such file or directory
[kellyry@ch12ldvela00 ~]$ exec ls
exec_test            file2             file3
. . .
```

Here's the weirdest part. Running the last line `exec ls` doesn't return. That is the terminal hangs and I can't communicate with it. I'm thinking this last problem could be an issue with Mobaxterm which I'm using to ssh in to the server.

Comment: Welcome to U&L!  What are you *trying* to do with `exec` here?  It's possible that you've misunderstood its purpose -- see eg. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/160429/how-does-exec-bash-builtin-work-internally .

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does exec bash builtin work internally?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/160429/how-does-exec-bash-builtin-work-internally)

Comment: I don't think that answers it. I edited my question with my expecatation. Judging from my reading of `man` for the command and going through a couple online examples such as: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/exec-command-in-linux-with-examples/ made me believe I was using it correctly. Easily could be wrong.

Comment: You missed out the `bash` command that precedes the `exec ls` in that example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the `bash` manpage:

> ```
> exec [-cl] [-a name] [command [arguments]]
> ```
>
> If `command` is specified, it replaces the shell.  No new process is created.
>
> [...]
>
> If `command` is not specified, any redirections take effect in the current shell, and the return status is 0.

## pipe to `exec`

The first thing you tried was

```
cat exec_test | exec
```

This sends `ls` to `exec` on the standard input, not as an argument.  `exec` is run with no arguments, and it has no redirections, so it does nothing.

If you wanted to run (or "execute") the command(s) in the file, that's not what `exec` is for.   You can do that with `source` (or the abbreviation `.`):

```
source exec_test
```

## pipe to `xargs exec`

The next thing you attempted

```
cat exec_test | xargs exec
```

`exec` is a bash [built-in](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html).  It's only available within bash, so `xargs` can't find it to execute it.

## `exec` in the main shell

Finally, you tried

```
exec ls
```

This ran `ls`, then hung the terminal.  That's because, as documented, it replaced the shell process.  Once `ls` has finished, there's no longer anything running in the terminal.  (Some terminal emulators will close automatically at this point.  Fortunately, yours did not close, so you could still see the output.)

The [example you were trying to follow](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/exec-command-in-linux-with-examples/) had an extra step:

```
bash
exec ls
```

This first starts a new `bash`, running as a child of the "top-level" one.  The `exec ls` then replaces that shell, and exits.  Then the parent shell resumes, so you're not left with a stuck terminal.

Comment: huh. that's terrific thanks. is there a way to execute the commands in the file from the commandline?

Comment: @user2183336 See my edit -- that's what `source` is for.  Further reading:  ["What is the difference between sourcing ('.' or 'source') and executing a file in bash?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/43882/what-is-the-difference-between-sourcing-or-source-and-executing-a-file-i)