# Access manpage(2) on OS X

Tags: osx, man, chmod, chgrp

In Mac OS X, at the end of the chmod man page, it shows

```
See also: chmod(2)
```

But when I enter

```
man chmod(2)
```

It says that there is no such man page. How can I access the man page chmod(2) man page? Is there a command to do this, or us it only accessible through the internet?

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/3586

Comment: The accepted answer to the linked question does explain how to specify a section, just after the list of sections.

Comment: Yes, it does, if the appropriate manpage is installed.

Comment: `man 2 chmod` will show you the manual page for `chmod` from section 2 of the manual.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You specify the section first:

```
man 2 chmod
```

See [`man man`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/man.1.html) for tons of information (although not so much in the [Mac OS X version](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/man.1.html)), including the meaning of the section numbers; 2 is for system calls, so the [`chmod(2)`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man2/chmod.2.html) manpage describes the `chmod` system call provided by the kernel.

On Mac OS X the system call manpages are provided in [Xcode Tools](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/), which need to be installed for all this to work; see the [documentation at the top of the on-line version of `chmod(2)`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man2/chmod.2.html).