# How to install section 5 of man pages?

Tags: debian, osx, man

`man tar` works and in the SEE ALSO section it references `tar(5)` but `man 5 tar` outputs `No entry for tar in section 5 of the manual`.

My primary goal is to get those for my OS X laptop. But I've seen them missing on Debian servers as well. `brew search man` doesn't offer me additional man pages to install. Any hints how to install the section 5 manpages? (tar is just an example, I'd need them in general)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Man section 5 is "File Formats and Conventions" and is not installed by default. see [What do the numbers in a man page mean?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3586/what-do-the-numbers-in-a-man-page-mean)

To install part of it on a Debian system, install:

```
sudo apt-get install libarchive-dev
```

From packages.debian.org:

> Package: libarchive-dev (3.1.2-11+deb8u1)
>
> The libarchive library provides a flexible interface for reading and
>   writing archives in various formats such as tar and cpio. libarchive
>   also supports reading and writing archives compressed using various
>   compression filters such as gzip and bzip2. The library is inherently
>   stream-oriented; readers serially iterate through the archive, writers
>   serially add things to the archive.

Double checking if man(5) tar page is installed:

```
dpkg -S /usr/share/man/man5/tar.5.gz
libarchive-dev:amd64: /usr/share/man/man5/tar.5.gz
```

Listing the files installed/owned by the package:

```
dpkg -L libarchive-dev | grep man
/usr/share/man
/usr/share/man/man5
/usr/share/man/man5/tar.5.gz
/usr/share/man/man5/mtree.5.gz
/usr/share/man/man5/libarchive-formats.5.gz
/usr/share/man/man5/cpio.5.gz
/usr/share/man/man3
/usr/share/man/man3/libarchive_internals.3.gz
/usr/share/man/man3/libarchive_changes.3.gz
/usr/share/man/man3/libarchive.3.gz
/usr/share/man/man3/archive_write_set_options.3.gz
/usr/share/man/man3/archive_write_open.3.gz
/usr/share/man/man3/archive_write_new.3.gz
/usr/share/man/man3/archive_write_header.3.gz
/usr/share/man/man3/archive_write_free.3.gz
/usr/share/man/man3/archive_write_format.3.gz
/usr/share/man/man3/archive_write_finish_entry.3.gz
/usr/share/man/man3/archive_write_filter.3.gz
/usr/share/man/man3/archive_write_disk.3.gz
/usr/share/man/man3/archive_write_data.3.gz
/usr/share/man/man3/archive_write_blocksize.3.gz
/usr/share/man/man3/archive_write.3.gz
/usr/share/man/man3/archive_util.3.gz
/usr/share/man/man3/archive_read_set_options.3.gz
/usr/share/man/man3/archive_read_open.3.gz
/usr/share/man/man3/archive_read_new.3.gz
/usr/share/man/man3/archive_read_header.3.gz
/usr/share/man/man3/archive_read_free.3.gz
/usr/share/man/man3/archive_read_format.3.gz
/usr/share/man/man3/archive_read_filter.3.gz
/usr/share/man/man3/archive_read_extract.3.gz
/usr/share/man/man3/archive_read_disk.3.gz
/usr/share/man/man3/archive_read_data.3.gz
/usr/share/man/man3/archive_read.3.gz
/usr/share/man/man3/archive_entry_time.3.gz
/usr/share/man/man3/archive_entry_stat.3.gz
/usr/share/man/man3/archive_entry_perms.3.gz
/usr/share/man/man3/archive_entry_paths.3.gz
/usr/share/man/man3/archive_entry_linkify.3.gz
/usr/share/man/man3/archive_entry_acl.3.gz
/usr/share/man/man3/archive_entry.3.gz
```

In OS/X you have already parts of the man 5 at /usr/share/man/man5 directory. Apart from copying there the aforementioned pages, have not investigated how to install them.

Comment: thanks, this answer lead me to the solution for OS X (written below), accepting this as it was leading to the correct solution

Answer (score 3):

on OSX the man pages are stored on `/usr/share/man/man5/`. Some of them are already installed (e.g. for fstab). But for e.g. tar it isn't.

Unfortunately there's no `libarchive-dev` package on homebrew. A workaround for just the man pages is to [download the libarchive sourcecode](http://www.libarchive.org/) for the version which is installed (`tar --version`) and copy the man pages over:

```
sudo cp doc/man/*.5 /usr/share/man/man5/
```

Comment: Yeah, that is it, aside from copying by hand have not seen a better solution, though I have not investigated extensively. +1

Comment: You might add `tar --version` and download the source for that version of libarchive.

Comment: @fd0 thanks for the hint, added that to my answer

Answer (score 0):

On a Fedora 22 system:

```
# rpm -qf /usr/share/man/man5/tar.5.gz
libarchive-3.1.2-14.fc22.x86_64
```

So try updating libarchive.