# crontab(1), crontab(5) what's the difference?

Tags: cron

I want to learn how to use crontab. I see there are two manual pages:

```
 crontab(1)
 crontab(5)
```

Why are there 2 manual pages? What are the differences between them? Do I need to study both in order to use crontab, or is one authoritative?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**crontab(1)** is the man page of crontab command.
**crontab(5)** is the man page of crontab file.

The man pages are divided in **sections** as described in [What do the numbers in a man page mean?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/3587/163129). Each section groups similar man pages. For example,  Section 1 holds user commands (commands runable by all users in the system). Section 8 covers SysAdmin commands (i.e. the commands that demand root access to be run). Section 5 covers file formats. See the link above for more info.

Another example would be **passwd(1)** which describes the **passwd command**, and **passwd(5)** which describes the **/etc/passwd file format**.

Comment: @steeldriver tks for the editing, its much clearer now