# A man page is available: Why the command generates: bash command not found?

Tags: command, man

Recently I was reading about techniques of encryption. I found crypt and encrypt commands. When I read man page it displays ok but when I run some examples system displayed message about bash command not found. I am working on RHEL 5.9.Is this behaviour of system is regular OR my OS is corrupted?. Please guide.

Answer (score 7):

Many manpages don’t describe commands available to the shell, but functions available to programs, or concepts, or configuration files. The manpages for [`crypt`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/crypt.3.html) and [`encrypt`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/encrypt.3.html) describe library functions.

You can get a quick idea of what a given manpage describes based on its section. Commands available to the shell are in section 1 or 8 (the latter for administrative commands, often only useful for `root`).

Note too that you can have section 1 or 8 manpages installed without having the corresponding command, so even if a manpage is in section 1 there is still no guarantee that the command is available. In some cases, manpages exist in different sections with the same name; you can specify the section you want:

```
man 1 printf
man 3 printf
```

See [What do the numbers in a man page mean?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/3586/86440) for details of the sections.

Comment: Also maybe not OP's problem but the man pages for commands in the sys path will be there but may not be in a normal user's path.

Answer (score 4):

No, your system is not broken. Many man pages exist to provide reference, but not necessarily about executable commands. The pages in the man system could contain:

1. Commands that are not available to the user.
   A common command (if the package sudo is installed) is `visudo`. It has a man entry in `man visudo` (as it should). But it is available **only** to the root user (as it should be). No user could execute it (without sudo), so, an user (prompt `$`) can not execute it and usually is not in the path of any other user except root. Thus:

   ```
   $ visudo
   bash: visudo: command not found
   ```

   But:

   ```
   $ sudo visudo
   ```

   or (as root, `#` prompt):

   ```
   # visudo
   ```

   would work.
2. General concepts like:

   ```
   man man
   man ascii
   ```

   Of course, `man` is also an executable, and the one to call man pages. Its manual page describe the concept of what a `section` means to the man system.

   That is important for concepts like `passwd` (the `-f` option means `find`):

   ```
   $ man -f passwd 
   passwd (1)           - change user password
   passwd (1ssl)        - compute password hashes
   passwd (5)           - the password file
   ```

   That shows that three pages in sections `1`, `1ssl` and `5` exist. The `1ssl` section will be available only if the `openssl` package has been installed. The man page for section 5 describe a file format, the `/etc/passwd` file format. The full list of section 5 (for linux) may be seen [here](https://linux.die.net/man/) or [here](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/dir_all_by_section.html#man5). That may have (depending of your OS) entries like:

   ```
   man acl
   ```

   Which is not an executable, nor is it expected to be (well, not yet).
3. The man entry may not even exist as a command or a file.

   If the package openssl is installed, there are man pages like:

   ```
   man dgst
   ```

   Which explain how a part of the openssl command will work, it is called as `openssl dgst`. There is no `dgst` command.

   Or:

   ```
   man ascii
   ```

   Which explain what is an ascii character.
4. Programming (C language) functions

   Many c language functions have a man page:

   ```
   man scanf
   ```

   There is no command, nor is it expected to exist, called `scanf`.

   But some pages exist in several sections:

   ```
   $ man -f printf
   printf (3)           - formatted output conversion
   printf (1)           - format and print data
   ```

   There is a command (section 1) called `printf` and there is a page for the c language function also called `printf`.