# How to list the headers of a man page?

Tags: text-processing, man

I want to view a list of the headers in a man page without reading all of the man page. For example, in the bash man page (`man bash.1`) there are many headers: `NAME`, `SYNOPSIS`, `COPYRIGHT`, `DESCRIPTION`, etc. In essence, I want a list like the one presented at the top of this [HTML man-page](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html). Is there a way to get that locally in the command line?

This can be useful in case you want to search for a section by a different name than they provide ("syntax" instead of "grammar") or sometimes you don't even know what you're looking for.

Comment: man-pages → Troff → https://www.gnu.org/software/groff/manual/groff.html ....... `man-pages` source code http://ftp.iij.ad.jp/pub/linux/kernel/linux/docs/man-pages/Archive/ ...  → `man-pages-5.12.tar.xz` .

Comment: Been [there](https://invisible-island.net/scripts/man2html.html).  Your example page also uses subsections `.SS` which none of the answers address, because those are formatted with a *few* leading blanks (before the prevailing left-margin of text).

Answer (score 4):

**Edit:**

I realized man page headers are the only text that is left-justified (for the most part). You can simply search `/^\w` after you open the man page and scroll up/down with `N`/`n`.

If you want to find the headers in a script, my original answer below might help or one of the others'.

**Original:**

Luckily, I found a solution based on [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/626946/408919) (go give them an upvote if this helped you).

```bsh
zcat $(man -w bash.1) | grep -i '^\.sh'
```

`man -w` gets the location of the man page source (e.g. `/usr/share/man/man1/bash.1.gz`). `zcat` uncompresses the source on the fly and sends it to `stdout`. And the `grep` call searches for lines starting with `.sh` (case-insensitive), which mark "section headers."

This ignores subsection headers (`.ss`), but you can remedy that by changing the filter to `'^\.s[sh]'` (Thanks Thomas).

Answer (score 4):

On systems using [`mandoc`](https://mandoc.bsd.lv/), you could ask for markdown-formatted output and then simply `grep` for lines starting with `#`:

```
$ man -T markdown man | grep '^#'
# NAME
# SYNOPSIS
# DESCRIPTION
# ENVIRONMENT
# FILES
# EXIT STATUS
# EXAMPLES
# SEE ALSO
# STANDARDS
# HISTORY
```

For manuals that this does not work for, you may instead go via HTML:

```
$ man -T html git | xmlstarlet sel -t -v '//h1/@id' -nl
NAME
SYNOPSIS
DESCRIPTION
OPTIONS
GIT_COMMANDS
HIGH
LOW
GUIDES
CONFIGURATION_MECHANISM
IDENTIFIER_TERMINOLOGY
SYMBOLIC_IDENTIFIERS
FILE/DIRECTORY_STRUCTURE
TERMINOLOGY
ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLES
DISCUSSION
FURTHER_DOCUMENTATION
AUTHORS
REPORTING_BUGS
SEE_ALSO
GIT
NOTES
```

Comment: Yeah. Unfortunately, this doesn't work by default on Ubuntu 20 (unless I'm doing something wrong). For example, `man -T markdown man | head` prints `No manual entry for markdown` trying to find a man page for markdown, and then outputs the raw source for man(1). Similar result with `-T html`.

Comment: @Noah with Ubuntu (well, mandb man), you can use `man --html=cat` instead (it generates HTML and uses the `cat` command to show it instead of your browser)

Answer (score 2):

Shorter, simpler alternative is to grep lines that start with something other than whitespace:

```
$ man git | grep '^\S'
GIT(1)                            Git Manual                            GIT(1)
NAME
SYNOPSIS
DESCRIPTION
OPTIONS
GIT COMMANDS
HIGH-LEVEL COMMANDS (PORCELAIN)
LOW-LEVEL COMMANDS (PLUMBING)
GUIDES
CONFIGURATION MECHANISM
IDENTIFIER TERMINOLOGY
SYMBOLIC IDENTIFIERS
FILE/DIRECTORY STRUCTURE
TERMINOLOGY
ENVIRONMENT VARIABLES
DISCUSSION
FURTHER DOCUMENTATION
AUTHORS
REPORTING BUGS
SEE ALSO
GIT
NOTES
Git 2.32.0                        06/06/2021                            GIT(1)
```

Those extra lines can also be removed:

```
$ man git | grep '^\S' | sed '1d;$d'
NAME
SYNOPSIS
DESCRIPTION
OPTIONS
GIT COMMANDS
HIGH-LEVEL COMMANDS (PORCELAIN)
LOW-LEVEL COMMANDS (PLUMBING)
GUIDES
CONFIGURATION MECHANISM
IDENTIFIER TERMINOLOGY
SYMBOLIC IDENTIFIERS
FILE/DIRECTORY STRUCTURE
TERMINOLOGY
ENVIRONMENT VARIABLES
DISCUSSION
FURTHER DOCUMENTATION
AUTHORS
REPORTING BUGS
SEE ALSO
GIT
NOTES
```

If you're already viewing it through `less` (i.e. what happens when you just `man git`), you can use `&` to show just matching lines. IOW, you can type `&^\S` and `less` will show you just the headers (and first and last line). To go back to showing the whole manpage, you can type `&` then <kbd>Enter</kbd>.