# What are the numbers in /etc/passwd? (and is there a way to find answers to these kind of questions without searching the internet)?

Tags: man, passwd

If i run `grep user /etc/passwd`, i get the string `user:x:1021:1021::/home/user:/bin/bash`. What does the numbers "1021:1021" mean? And is there a offline way to find what these mean? If i do `man passwd` i get information about the command, not the file

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`man 5 passwd`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/passwd.5@@shadow-utils.html):

> `/etc/passwd` contains one line for each user account, with seven fields delimited by colons (“:”). These fields are:
>
> - login name
> - optional encrypted password
> - numerical user ID
> - numerical group ID
> - user name or comment field
> - user home directory
> - optional user command interpreter

Well, that's pretty much it.

<sub>(`man7.org` has two versions of that man page, the above is the one I had on Debian. <sub>Luckily, there's really no variation in the contents of `passwd` or `shadow`, at least on Linuxen, I think.</sub> )</sub>

---

The meaning of that `5` is described by e.g. [the man page for `man` itself](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/man.1.html), it tells that the manual "sections" are:

> ```
> 1   Executable programs or shell commands
> 2   System calls (functions provided by the kernel)
> 3   Library calls (functions within program libraries)
> 4   Special files (usually found in /dev)
> 5   File formats and conventions eg /etc/passwd
> 6   Games
> 7   Miscellaneous (including macro packages and conventions),
>     e.g. man(7), groff(7)
> 8   System administration commands (usually only for root)
> ```

You're looking for the file `passwd`, so section 5 it is.

`crontab` is similar that it's a command (`crontab(1)`) and a file (`crontab(5)`). Also, `open` appears to have man pages for a command (in Linux, alias for `openvt(1)`), a system call (`open(2)`), and a Perl pragma (`open(3perl)`). Section numbers with tailing text like `3perl` are also somewhat common.

Use `whatis foo` to find out if there's more than one match:

```
$ whatis passwd
passwd (1)           - change user password
passwd (1ssl)        - compute password hashes
passwd (5)           - the password file
```

<sub>(oh, right, there's also `openssl passwd`)</sub>

Then there's `apropos`, which ["[searches] the manual page names and descriptions"](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/apropos.1.html). Usually giving a lot more hits.

See also: [What do the numbers in a man page mean?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/3586/170373)

---

If you have multiple chapters where the same command/config file appears, this is usually mentioned in the `man` page. E.g. at the bottom of `man passwd` one will find

> SEE ALSO
>
> chpasswd(8), passwd(5), shadow(5), usermod(8).

hinting to a chapter 5 entry for passwd. And in reverse `man 5 passwd` has

> SEE ALSO
>
> crypt(3), getent(1), getpwnam(3), login(1), passwd(1), pwck(8), pwconv(8), pwunconv(8), shadow(5), su(1), sulogin(8).

Comment: Not to forget the alternative to `man`: `info` - which (for some applications) is a bit more detailed and has hyperlinks in the text allowing one to jump to another page. E.g. when `info man` talks about `man`'s `--ascii` option and links to what ASCII is.

Comment: @FelixJN, yes, `info` is particularly relevant with GNU tools, where the man pages sometimes omit all the interesting stuff. (Or are just made as stubs by third parties, e.g. I think Debian has done that so that everything would have at least _some_ man page.) Luckily, the GNU documentation is usually available online too, so there's not so much need to look at `info`.